# Debugging from Web - Embedded boards

Tags: javascript, embedded

So excited to asks experts on this platform. I don't know where my question fits but anyone familiar with ARM mbed or dev.ti.com?

Let me give you a clue. On these website they provide an online IDE (just like desktop version) on which you can build an "Embedded Software" and **download, run and Debug** on some target board like (TIVA C, STM32 etc.) connected to PC. As far as i know javascript on web page doesn't have any access to local machine. So how does it access computer ports and computer drivers etc?

WEB Experts please give me a clue like how browser is allowed to access local computer resources??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As far as i know javascript on web page doesn't have any access to local machine. So how does it access computer ports and computer drivers etc?

You can access your local machine through a server. For example to ask it for a certain file or to run some commands/code through an API you define.

> How browser is allowed to access local computer resources?

The browser is a program on your machine. The programming language(s) in which the browser was built provides *interfaces* to communicate with your system on a low level.

It's worth mentioning that **the browser and the web application it renders are not the same and do not communicate in the same way with your system**.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you're correct - Javascript running in your browser does not have access to many of the resources needed for reprogramming and debugging a development board.

However, there are a few ways to work around this:

### 1. Build development boards that can work with the hardware APIs the browser already allows access to.

This usually involves using APIs in unexpected ways. The integrated [debug firmware](https://github.com/ARMmbed/DAPLink) on all mbed boards emulates a USB disk drive. The user can download the firmware file from the mbed site and then copy it onto the disk drive to install the firmware on the development board.

There are also some more creative (mis)uses of hardware APIs. For example, this [Chibitronics board](https://chibitronics.com/programming-chibi-chip/) relies on the browser sending the new firmware via audio output. I have also heard about - but cannot find a suitable link to - an example of repurposing the U2F protocol to do double duty as a firmware update mechanism.

Because this approach repurposes existing APIs, it is generally widely supported, but requires extra work on the device side to fit a square peg into a round hole.

### 2. Install a native application/extension that accesses hardware and allows the website to access the hardware through the extension.

This is the approach used by TI Cloud Tools, Arduino Create, and Codebender. Once a user has installed a companion application, that application allows the website to access anything that a normal IDE would be able to access.

In a sense, this approach is very similar to building a native application with a very cloud-centric UI.

### 3. Extend browsers to add new hardware APIs that can be used to program development boards.

The [WebBluetooth](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/) and [WebUSB](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/) draft standards add new APIs to allow Javascript to access BLE and USB devices directly, which can then be used to communicate directly with connected USB debug hardware or BLE bootloaders.

micro:bit is currently testing a [beta program](https://support.microbit.org/support/solutions/articles/19000084059-beta-testing-web-usb) that uses WebUSB to directly program and communicate with micro:bit boards.

These APIs are only implemented in Chrome, so they are not a universal solution. Additionally, due to security restrictions and driver issues, not all existing hardware is compatible with WebUSB.